# I used two load_cnosdb processes to import data, and the client occasionally reported an error: 1001 node failover

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I used two [load_cnosdb](https://github.com/cnosdb/tsdb-comparisons) processes to import data, and the client occasionally reported an error: 1001 node failover.

the version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 6c757da5e31800c4c802bd2cc2f5877b9d392ae7

```
cat cnodb-iot-seed-123-scale-100-2023.gz|gunzip|load_cnosdb --batch-size 11000 --workers 80 --urls http://127.0.0.1:8912 

cat cnodb-iot-seed-123-scale-100-2016.gz|gunzip|load_cnosdb --batch-size 11000 --workers 80 --db-name benchmark001  --urls http://127.0.0.1:8902
```

A few minutes later， the error log as follow:

```
Error writing: [DebugInfo: worker #18, dest url: http://127.0.0.1:8902] Invalid write response (status 422): {"error_code":"050016","error_message":"Node failover: 2001, error: Status { code: Unknown, message: \"request timed out\", source: Some(Elapsed(())) }"}
...
Error writing: [DebugInfo: worker #31, dest url: http://127.0.0.1:8912] Invalid write response (status 422): {"error_code":"050016","error_message":"Node failover: 1001, error: Status { code: Unknown, message: \"request timed out\", source: Some(Elapsed(())) }"}
```

I check the cnosdb's log and  meta's log, there is no error info.

The cnosdb process is also normal.So what is node failover?